# How can I make Rails ActiveRecord automatically truncate values set to attributes with maximum length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, max

Assuming that I have a class such as the following:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, :length => {:maximum => 10}

end
```

Is there a way (gem to install?) that I can have ActiveRecord automatically truncate values according to maximum length?

For instance, when I write:

```
b = Book.new
b.title = "123456789012345" # this is longer than maximum length of title 10
b.save
```

should save and return true?

If there is not such a way, how would you suggest that I proceed facing such a problem more generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a new validator that does truncation. Here is how I did that:

I created the "validators" folder inside "app" folder and then created the file "length_truncate_validator.rb" with the following content:

```
class LengthTruncateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    ml = options[:maximum]
    record.send("#{attribute}=", value.mb_chars.slice(0,ml)) if value.mb_chars.length > ml unless value.nil? or ml.nil?
  end

  class << self
    def maximum(record_class, attribute)
      ltv = record_class.validators_on(attribute).detect { |v| v.is_a?(LengthTruncateValidator) }
      ltv.options[:maximum] unless ltv.nil?
    end
  end

end
```

And inside my model class I have something like:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, :length_truncate => {:maximum => 10}

end
```

which is quite handy and works the way I require.

But still, if you think that this one can be improved or done in another way, you are welcome.

Comment: This works, but I would call it more of a hack since it's using a validator, but not actually performing any validations.

Comment: I agree with Matt.  While it is possible to use the validation hooks to do this, it is a hack because not a Rails-style validation.  Validators are not expected to modify the object, only to add to the errors collection as needed.  If you want to force truncations, then (redundantly) validate the field length, just use karmajunkie's solution, but fire it using the before_validation callback, and just use the standard length validator.

Comment: Validations check state. Use callbacks to change state.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you want the value truncated if its too long, you don't really need a validation, because it will always pass. I'd handle that like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :truncate_values
  def truncate_values
    self.title = self.title[0..9] if self.title.length > 10
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not fully agree with you. My business rule says: "title less or equal to 10 is valid even if this is a result of truncation". `validates :title, :length => {:maximum => 10, :truncate => true}` would have been the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

This may not have been an option in 2011, but now there's a `before_validation` callback that will work.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation do
    if self.params && self.params.length > 1000
      self.params = self.title[0...10] 
    end
  end

  validate :title, length: { maximum: 10 }, allow_nil: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using the before_validation callback. Here's my stab that automatically truncates all strings to within the database's limit

```
  before_validation :truncate_strings

  def truncate_strings
    self.class.columns.each do |column|
      next if column.type != :string

      if self[column.name].length > column.limit
        self[column.name] = self[column.name][0...column.limit]
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: does this pick it up from the column definition? eg varchar(132) would truncate at char 132